# Greedy Online Bin Packing Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, greedy, bin

I'm trying to find a greedy solution to the online bin packing problem. There are some changes to this problem compared to the original bin packing problem. First, each bin has capacity C > 0. Also, each item i has weight w_i <= C. Since this is an online bin packing problem, each item must be placed in a bin (and never moved again) before the next item can be processed. Also, if we create a new bin, then we can't return back to the old bin and place more items in it later.

My greedy algorithm is the next fit solution (fit as many items as possible into one bin while the total weight is less than C). When we can't fit the next item, we create a new bin.

But I am having difficulty proving the optimality for this solution. I tried using a greedy ahead argument, but got stuck.

Any hints or guideline would be great!

Comment: I think the trick is to sort the items into weight order, then keep packing the heaviest which will fit until you have nothing more you can put in.

Comment: This is an online problem, so the items come in one at a time. Hence, there isn't a list of items to sort. An item must be placed in a bin before the next one can come in.

Comment: Sorry.  You learn something every day... I thought you meant a bin-packing problem which is online, I now know that there is an online-bin-packing problem :-)  Since you cannot change the order of packing and you can only pack stuff in the current bin, there doesn't seem much scope for optimisation !  FWIW, I found [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bin-packing-problem-minimize-number-of-used-bins/) online (hoho).

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know what an online problem until I tried to solve this one. I'm still trying to determine a way to give a formal proof of as to why this algorithm is optimal given the problem constraints. Thanks though!